# Images are not updated by percentage

Tags: javascript

In a game, the end boss has a status bar. At the start, the end boss has 100% life, and each time it is hit, it loses 20% life. Unfortunately, the status bar does not reflect this. The problem is that 100% is displayed first and as soon as it is hit, the status bar jumps directly to 0% instead of displaying the images in between. When debugging, I only noticed that this.percentage has the value 100 at the beginning, with every further hit this.percentage is undefined.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve the problem?

```
class StatusbarEndboss extends DrawableObject { 
    IMAGES = [ 
        'img/7_statusbars/2_statusbar_endboss/0.png', 
        'img/7_statusbars/2_statusbar_endboss/20.png', 
        'img/7_statusbars/2_statusbar_endboss/40.png', 
        'img/7_statusbars/2_statusbar_endboss/60.png', 
        'img/7_statusbars/2_statusbar_endboss/80.png', 
        'img/7_statusbars/2_statusbar_endboss/100.png' 
    ]; 
    //percentage = 100; 
    constructor() { 
        super(); 
        this.loadImages(this.IMAGES); 
        this.x = 40; 
        this.y = 50; 
        this.width = 240; 
        this.height = 80; 
        this.percentage = 100; 
        this.setPercentage(this.percentage); 
    } 
    setPercentage(percentage) { 
        this.percentage = percentage; 
        let path = this.IMAGES[this.resolveImageIndex(this.percentage)]; 
        this.img = this.imageCache[path]; 
    } 
    resolveImageIndex() { 
        console.log('Current Percentage:', this.percentage);
        if (this.percentage == 100) { 
            return 5; 
        } else if (this.percentage > 80) { 
            return 4; 
        } else if (this.percentage > 60) { 
            return 3; 
        } else if (this.percentage > 40) { 
            return 2; 
        } else if (this.percentage > 20) { 
            return 1; 
        } else { 
            return 0; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The method in which setPercentage is called is this one:

```
handleEndbossCollision(enemy) {
        if (enemy.isCollided) {
            return;
        }

        enemy.hits += 1;

        if (enemy.hits === 4) {
            enemy.dead = true;
            this.character.endboss_dead.play();
            enemy.stopMoving();
            return;
        }

        enemy.isCollided = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            enemy.isCollided = false;
        }, 1650);

        if (!enemy.isAlert) {
            enemy.isAlert = true;
        }
        this.character.endboss_hurt.play();
        enemy.stopMoving();
        enemy.hurt = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            enemy.hurt = false;
            enemy.resumeMoving();
            enemy.speed *= 1.3;
        }, 1500);
        this.statusBarEndboss.setPercentage();
    }
```

Comment: If `this.percentage` is undefined after calling `setPercentage`, the only reason I can see for that in the code you shared is that you _called_ `setPercentage` with an incorrect first argument. (or perhaps a binding of `this` issue). Share the code that calls `setPercentage`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added the call to the main question.

Comment: You're not passing the `percentage` argument when you call `this.statusBarEndboss.setPercentage();`

Comment: Where does is the updated percentage supposed to come from in `handleEndbossCollision()`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks that helped a lot. I have changed it to this.statusBarEndboss.setPercentage(this.statusBarEndboss.percentage - 20);
Now it works.